# Patient selection based on medication use, while medication use is the outcome measure too

Tags: epidemiology

I am working on a heart failure project to look at rate of prescribing change over time. Because the data does not contain date of diagnosis, so a patient study entry date is defined as the first time when a patient uses the heart failure specific drugs such as some beta blockers. However the change in the use of beta blockers is also the outcome measure.

So the denominator is the dynamic monthly number of patients identfied as HF patients. 
And the numerator is the monthly number of beta blocker scripts issued.

My questions are that:

1. since the denominator is identified because of the numerator, can I still use this approach to calculate the rate?
2. a possible argument is that we only identify the HF patients using one time point drug use to form the denominator, their drug utilisations over time are actually unknown. Therefore, the rate calculation to look at changes in the rate of scripts would not necessarily be biased, because they may not adhere to the treatment, or increase the number scripts or stop using it, etc.  So, is this a reasonable argument to justify the rate calculation in this circumstance?

Comment: Logically they can only change if they are already on beta-blockers so I cannot see what your doubt is which you express in your question 1.

Comment: It may not matter. But the confusion is that it actually should be 1. Because they are HF patients, then we can see whether the prescription changes. But now, 2. because they are on beta-blocker, then they are idenified as HF patients,  and we want to see whether their beta-blocker changes. So my question is about the second situation, the other way around

Comment: In situation 1, it is patients are "at risk" of being prescribed a beta-blocker, some patients may not, while in situation 2 every one has been prescribed the drug, they are not "at risk" anymore. That leads to my second point in the post.